# How to serve Flask static files using Nginx?

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I've a web application with this structure:

```
|
|__ static
   |__style.less
   |__images
|__ myapp.py
|__ wsgi.py
```

I've managed to run the web application using nginx and wsgi, but the problem is that the static files are not served, i mean, the server can't find them when i go to their URL. It gives me 404.

Here's my nginx configuration file part:

```
 server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name xxxxxxx.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /myapp {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/public_html/myapp/myapp.sock;
}
```

Is there something missing?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Add this to your nginx configuration

```
location ^~ /static/  {
    include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    root /project_path/;
}
```

replace `/project_path/` with your **app's absolute path**, you should note that it **doesn't include static directory** and all the contents inside  `/project_path/static/` will be serverd in url `/static/`.

Comment: Thank you, your code worked, but right now I see that the templates are not working on the website (it's just showing me the 404.html template that I've created all the time, and doesn't use the other templates in the `templates` directory.

Comment: Just make sure whether templates are inside static folder

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block

Comment: @JohnMagistr Adding root in every location block is not recommended but you can override the server root with root inside location which is alright.

Comment: What does the ^~ do?

Comment: @TomClose, in general, the location directive takes a URI and tries to match it with a location block. There are a variety of optional location modifiers with various meanings that can be placed between the location keyword and the location match (/static/ in this case), and in this case, the ^~ modifier says that if this particular location match is the best match for the URI, then to choose it and not perform any further regular expression matching.

 https://www.keycdn.com/support/nginx-location-directive

Answer (score 4):

From [How to Configure NGINX for a Flask Web Application](https://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/how-to-configure-nginx-for-a-flask-web-application/)

I found this solution to be better:

```
location /static/  {
    alias /<path to project>/static;
}
```

Replace `<path to project>` with your project's directory, of course.

Note in this solution that `static` is included in the path! This is really good for security! The risk of accidentally serving application source files is reduced. By default flask puts the source files in the `<path to project>` and a small mistake in configurations could make these source files visible to attackers.

- Update: the path of `location` must end with `/`.

Comment: Jason, this is less secure and vulnerable to alias traversal attacks. See https://github.com/yandex/gixy/blob/master/docs/en/plugins/aliastraversal.md