# NGINX default page is being shown instead of Flask app

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I have displayed my NGINX configuration below. One of my Flask applications work (the one above), however the one below does not. The weird thing is, they were both working the other day, now the one below (example2) just returns the NGINX default page.

File structure:

```
/Signup/
    /static/
       /assets/
            /bootstrap/
            /css/
            /fonts/
            /img/
            /js/
    /templates/
        register.html
    main.py
```

NGINX Config:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;

    server_name example1.domain.net;

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
}


server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;

    server_name example2.domain.net;

    location ^~ /static/ {

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6000;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        root /root/Signup/;

    }
}
```

Example 1 works as it should, example2 (second server block does not).

Edit: Thought I should note, I have no prior experience with NGINX, please don't assume.

Comment: Can you share an example of the URL request that you are testing the second server with? Are you including /static/ in the URL request to the second server?

Comment: Did you enable the NGINX server block configuration for the second?

Comment: Ignore the last comment. Can you try using the Alias keyword. See link here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

Comment: Ok, so a question I tried following on Stackoverflow is linked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682179/how-to-serve-flask-static-files-using-nginx I followed this to get the static files to be served. I'd like it so when the users go to example2.domain.net (not /static/), the template is rendered?

Comment: What's your directory structure for the Flask app? Which directory is the template located in? List your directory structure like the OP did in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682179/how-to-serve-flask-static-files-using-nginx

Comment: I have updated the post with the file structure of the Flask application, thanks.