# Flask serve static css files outside root directory

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask setup that looks like this:

```
+---server
|   \---src
|       |   app.py
|       |   
|       \---templates
|               index.html
|               
\---static
    +---assets
    |       bg.jpg
    +---css
    |       main.css  
    \---js
            main.js
```

How can I configure `app.py` to serve the static folder without changing the directory structure that I have now?

This is what my `app.py` looks like right now:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def render_static_index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I've already tried to use the `static_url_path` optionn but I got an error saying that the path must start with a "/" character so I couldn't do ../static or the absolute path to the folder.

Comment: did you check documentation for option `static=path` ?

Comment: @furas Yes, but I got an error saying that the path must start with a "/" character so I couldn't do ../static or the absolute path to the folder.

Comment: Doc [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/) - `Flask(..., static_folder=...)` . - it has to be relative to ` root_path`. But preferred method is to use web server like Apache/NGINX to serve static files and then you have to set it in Apache/NGINX configuration

Comment: BTW: if you already tried something and got error then you should describe it in question. If you skip this kind of information then you only waste your and our time.

Comment: BTW: [How to serve Flask static files using Nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682179/how-to-serve-flask-static-files-using-nginx)

Comment: I'm not looking to use nginx, I would like to use flask. Is there any was to "redirect" the folder path to the one above the root folder?

Comment: you got in previous comment - `Flask(..., static_folder=...)`, not `static_url_path`

Comment: @furas, I tried that and python didn't give me any errors, but it still didn't render the files in static.

Comment: did you use path relative to `root_path` like is in documentation ? Do you run in debug mode - `app.run(debug=True)` ? I'm not sure if `Flask` servers static files if you don't run debug mode and you may have to use `Apache/NGINX` to serve static files  (or maybe it was with `Django`)

Comment: BTW: maybe with `debug=True` it will show you more details about problem.

Comment: in your example it can be `static_folder="../../static"` - But in HTML you still have to use `/static` - like `url="/static/css/main.css"`.