# Flask & uwsgi not rendering files from static folder

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, static, uwsgi

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04), everything went well but the app is not rendering files from static folder (css, images, scripts, etc).

I gave every permission to the folder (sudo chmod a+rwx static), and the sub-folders, but still not rendering.

The code i'm using is one that worked before with almost the same config (Ubuntu 18.04 back in the day)

```
app = Flask(__name__,static_url_path='',static_folder="static")
```

And my nginx config file :

```
 location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/home/sydney/ecocathlon/ecocathlon.sock;
}
 location /static {
     root /home/sydney/ecocathlon/static;
 }
```

Do you have any ideas on how i can allow the program to access to the folder ?

Thanks in advance,

Sydney R.

Comment: What requests do you try and what do you get in response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `alias` instead of `root`:

```
location /static {
     alias /home/sydney/ecocathlon/static;
}
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59074896/2052575).

Also I'd leave `static_url_path` out of your application definition, and also `static_folder` as you're just setting this to the default:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

`static_url_path` controls how the app generates URLs to static files, so you'd be forcing it to generate links like `/something.js` instead of `/static/something.js` by setting this to an empty string.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you and have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with serving the files using wsgi check [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/)

It also makes simple to migrate to a CDN later, if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
static_url_path=''
```

instead of the default

```
static_url_path=None
```

you're telling Flask that static resources will live at `/` instead of `/static`. This will confound attempts to use

```
location /static {
```

because there is no `/static` url path. But if you tried

```
location / {
```

requests would never reach the home page of your app.

Either remove `static_url_path=''` (and retain `location /static`) or specify individual locations for every route that resolves to a file that you want nginx to server up directly.